# convert timestamp to month in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get month from data base directly, means need to convert time stamp to month

```
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
{
    $this->db->select_sum('total_price');
    $this->db->where("date(orders_details.timestamp)" ,$i); ///here I want month 

    $this->db->order_by("orders_details.id desc");
    $q= $this->db->get("orders_details");
    $res=$q->result();

    if($q->num_rows()>0) {
        echo $price=$res[0]->total_price;
    }
}

$this->db->where("date('m', strtotime(orders_details.timestamp))" ,$i);
```

I tried this above code but its not working.

Comment: hi, yo can replace your where with this `$this->db->where("MONTH() ", $i)`

Comment: okk, i am checking..

Comment: No its not working

Comment: or try with php like `$this->db->where(date('m'), $i)`

Comment: but i need to check with time stamp

Comment: I did like this 
 $this->db->where('MONTH(orders_details.timestamp)',"0".$i);